# How Would I add a constructor to this code.

Tags: c++, openframeworks

Hey I am trying to make this space game. Now I have developed my ship, and am able to display it. However I would like to be able to use the class for more than one object. I can do this with a constructor but have no clue how to get a constructor working, what changes would I need to make to my code to make the object take an int value as a constructor and allow me to make multiple ships with the code by calling the object.

Here is my header file.
       //
    //  Ship.hpp
    //  Zerg_Invasion
    //
    //  Created by Flik Wolf on 11/9/15.
    //
    //

```
#ifndef Ship_h
#define Ship_h

#include <stdio.h>

#include "ofMain.h"

class Ship {
public:
    // Constructor
    Ship();

    // Methods
    void moveLeft();
    void moveRight();
    void load();
    void draw();
    void fire();
    void keyPressed();

    // Properties
    int x;
    int y;
    ofColor color;
    ofImage cat;
};



#endif
```

and here is my CPP file.

```
//
//  Ship.cpp
//  Zerg_Invasion
//
//  Created by Flik Wolf on 11/9/15.
//
//

#include "Ship.h"

Ship::Ship() {
    // Set the initial color
    //color.set( ofRandom(255), ofRandom(255), ofRandom(255));

    // Initial x position of the ball
    x = 450;

    // Initial y position of the ball
    y = 200;
}

void Ship::moveLeft() {
    x -= 10;

}

void Ship::moveRight() {
    x += 10;

}

void Ship::load() {
    cat.load("spaceShip.png");
}

void Ship::draw() {
    cat.draw(x, y);
//  ofCircle(x, y, 30);

}

void Ship::fire() {
    ofSetColor(255, 255, 255);
    ofCircle(x, 200, 2);
}
```

Also here is the .h and .cpp files for Openframeworks which I am using for graphics.

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "Ship.h"

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp {

public:
    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();

    void keyPressed(int key);
    void keyReleased(int key);
    void mouseMoved(int x, int y);
    void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
    void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
    void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button);
    void mouseEntered(int x, int y);
    void mouseExited(int x, int y);
    void windowResized(int w, int h);
    void dragEvent(ofDragInfo dragInfo);
    void gotMessage(ofMessage msg);


    Ship theShip;


};


#include "ofApp.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::setup() {
    // Smooth edges
    ofEnableSmoothing();

    // Fixed framerate
    ofSetFrameRate(120);

    theShip.load();

    // No need to define the initial position of the ball
    // because the Ball constructor does it for you
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update() {
    // theShip.move();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw() {
    ofBackground(0);
    std::vector <int> nums;
    nums.push_back(0);
    nums.push_back(1);
    nums.push_back(3);
    nums.push_back(4);
    nums.push_back(5);
    nums.push_back(6);
    nums.push_back(7);
    nums.push_back(8);

    cout << nums[0] << endl;
    cout << nums[1] << endl;

    theShip.draw();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::keyPressed(int key) {
    if (key == 'a')
    {
        theShip.moveLeft();
    }
    if (key == 'd')
    {
        theShip.moveRight();
    }
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::keyReleased(int key) {

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mouseMoved(int x, int y) {

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button) {

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mousePressed(int x, int y, int button) {
    theShip.fire();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button) {

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mouseEntered(int x, int y) {

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mouseExited(int x, int y) {

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::windowResized(int w, int h) {

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::gotMessage(ofMessage msg) {

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::dragEvent(ofDragInfo dragInfo) {

}
```

Comment: What specific issue are you having?

Comment: Which book are you using? This is very basic and should be covered within the first few chapters.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the constructor in your case should only produce **one** ship, and this should be the case with *all* object constructors.

However, it's still easy enough to create and maintain multiple ships (as you've implemented them) if you use a container like `std::vector`.

#### Containing multiple ships:

To create a container for your ships, you can use a vector like so:

```
std::vector<Ship> Ships;
```

#### Adding new ships:

To add additional ships to it, you can use `std::vector::push_back()`:

```
Ships.push_back(Ship()); //Adds a new ship to 'Ships'
```

#### Updating the ships:

There are a couple of ways to cycle through your ships:

```
for (auto& i : Ships) 
    i.Update(); //Some updating function for each ship
```

Or, if you need to keep track of the specific position of each ship inside the vector:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Ships.size(); ++i)
    Ships[i].Update() //The same updating function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to get the `x` and `y` as constructor argument?

in the .h file:

```
struct Ship {
    // Constructor
    Ship(int _x = 450, int _y = 200);
// ...
```

in the cpp file:

```
Ship::Ship(int _x, int _y) : x{_x}, y{_y} {
    // Set the initial color
    //color.set( ofRandom(255), ofRandom(255), ofRandom(255));

}
```